# BackgroundWorker doesn't handle exception

Tags: c#, multithreading

I've really read all other similar threads on Stackoverflow. Nothing works for me...
I throw an exception of type "Exception" but i can't handle the exception.

I've tried it in the DoWork Progress, in the CompletedEvent (with try/catch, witch e.error....)

```
void bgGetResponse_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        ConvertByte(myFile);
        myFile= null;
    }
}

void bgGetResponse_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    byte[] test= new byte[] { 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
    //Here the error occured (just with  throw new Exception("error"))
    //The method only throws an exception (for test purposes)
    testResponse= _configManager.GetResponse(test, 0);
}

GetResponse(...)
{

   throw new Exception("..!");

}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks for your efforts

Comment: Handling the exception in RunWorkerCompleted is the way to go. I see nothing wrong with your code. Please provide a minimal working sample project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "can't handle" the exception you mean can't use `catch`, that's true.  You just use the Error property.  You could "throw" that in your Completed event handler; but then you stack frame will be different.

e.g.:

```
try
{
    if(e.Error != null) throw(e.Error)
    // handle success case
}
catch(MyException exception)
{
    // handle specific error.
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mean that I can't catch the exception. What do you mean with "You could throw that in your completed event handler, but..."?

Comment: @user1011394 added detail to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've try it. The behavior is the same. I'm not able to catch the exception... In debugging mode (VS) the debugger jumps to the failure (throw new Exception("..!")) and if I run the .exe file, the application just crashing...

Comment: @user1011394 You'll have to provide more detail because the code I provided works just fine.  i.e. there's something else going on there that you haven't detailed, until we know what that is, we can only guess (usually wrong).

Comment: The only thing is, that GetResponse() is in a DLL which is included to the project. But GetResponse() has just one line..."throw new Exception" ... there is no more detail information, that's really really strange

Comment: Ah I figured out that if I write "throw new exception" in DoWork method, the exception handling works fine. But if I try to use the method whithin the DLL it doesn't work...

Comment: @user1011394 "use the method whithin the DLL" that's a bit vague.  I've never had a problem with DLLs and BackgroundWorker...

Answer (score 2):

I usually just catch it in the work Method and set the result to it.

```
private void BGW_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    e.Result = ex;
}
```

Then look in the Completed event,

private void BGW_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;

```
try
{
    Exception ex = e.Result as Exception;
    if (null != ex)
        throw ex;
```

...

Answer (score 1):

Any unhandled exceptions occuring in the BackgroundWorkers DoWork function will cause the worker to fire RunWorkerCompleted where the event argument will contain the error.